# Convert dlang char/wchar to string/wstring

Tags: d

How do I convert a single char/wchar to a single-character string/wstring in d? I can't find anything online that doesn't talk about char* or wchar*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As strings are just `immutable(char)[]`, you can construct them like any other array with chars:

```
char a = 'a';
string s = [a];
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a few different options. One is to get a pointer by just taking the address of it. You generally shouldn't use this but you should be aware it is possible.

```
char a = 'a';
char[] b = (&a)[0 .. 1]; // &a gets a pointer, [0..1] slices the single element
string c = b.idup; // copy it into a new string
```

If you used a wchar you could get a wstring out of it this way. Then std.conv.to can convert between string and wstring.

Speaking of std.conv.to, that's the next option and is actually the easiest:

```
import std.conv;
char a = 'a'; // or wchar
string b = to!string(a); // or to!wstring
```

In the real world I'd probably suggest you use this for maximum convenience and simplicity, but you lose a bit of efficiency in some cases.

Thus, the third option I'll present is `std.utf.encode`.

```
import std.utf;
char[4] buffer;
auto len = encode(buffer, a); // put the char in the buffer
writeln(buffer[0 .. len]); // slice the buffer. idup it if you want string specifically
```

This works for any input: char, wchar, or dchar, and will encode multi-byte code points into the string as well. To get a wstring, use `wchar[2]` for the buffer isntead. This is a good balance of correctness and efficiency, just at the trade of being a little less convenient.

Comment: for more memory safety you should try to do `const(char)[] b = (&a)[0 .. 1];` instead. I believe this kind of question could be more popular, so I think it might also be beneficial to mention when you actually need `string` and when `const(char)[]` is enough, and that you should prefer taking in `scope const(char)[]` in your own API parameters and how you can avoid GC calls / `.idup` with it.